# Why does this recurssive program give me this output?

Tags: java, recursion

I am busy studying recursion in java, and am having difficulty understanding how it works most the time. I have a sample program from the book, which they ask you to find the output of if n = 3:

```
public void printX(int n){

    if(n <= 0)
        System.out.print(0);
    else{
        printX(n-1);
        System.out.print(n);
        printX(n - 2);

    }
}
```

I thought the outcome would be "231". However after typing the code into Eclipse and running the program, the outcome turned out to be "010203010" for the code.

Can someone help me understand why this is the output rather than what I thought?

Comment: Well you do not prevent a call from happening when `n-1` or `n-2` is less than or equal to `0`...

Comment: to understand recursion you first need to understand recursion

Comment: Have you been taught about tree structures and depth-first?

Comment: I have learned of them, it is simply that I do not understand how the base case is actually working in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand this behavior is to step through line by line; you can do this with a debugger.

The short answer: you thought it would print 2 first, because when `n` is 3 the first thing it does is call `printX(n-1)` which is `printX(2)`.  But when `n` is `2`, what does it do?  Just print 2?  No... it first calls `printX(n-1)` which this time means `printX(1)`.  And so on

Answer (score 0):

The thing to pick up on here is that the calling function will always finish *after* the called function. Each time `printX` is called the calling function pauses and waits until the called function completes before continuing execution. One way of thinking about it is that it is a means of nesting functions within each other.

Answer (score -1):

Please rewrite the code as follows:

```
public void printX(int n){

    if(n >0)
        System.out.print(n);
         n--;
        printX(n)
    else{

        System.out.print(n);

        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Question is to help him understand, this code should do it, a bit.

Comment: Since OP doesn't understand recursion, perhaps editing the question to add an explanation would help.